# Redis pubsub message queue but with callback, as in ZeroMQ

Tags: node.js, redis, zeromq

I have found the following code that implements an asynchronous message queue (actually there is no queue, only files) with ZeroMQ and Node.js

```
setInterval(function() {
  var value = { id: i++, date: new Date() };
  WriteFile(value.id + ".dat", value);

  client.send(value, function(result) {
    console.log(value, result);
    DeleteFile(value.id + ".dat");
  });
}, 10000);
```

The code is from [here](http://naviger.com/?p=39).

The functions "WriteFile" and "DeleteFile" are defined later in the code, but there is nothing extraordinary there.

The function "client.send" is also defined in another file, where the callback is defined. Clearly there is a provision from ZeroMQ to have a callback when the message transmission is successful.

Now I want to do something like this but with Redis pubsub instead of ZeroMQ for simplicity. As I understand it, there is no callback in the "publish" function from the node_redis module.

My question is, is there a way to implement something like this? I really like the idea of writing files and then deleting them whet the transmission is complete, but I would like it done in Redis. I know I am grasping at straws, but if anyone has any ideas, I will gladly listen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All of the `redis` module's commands [have an optional callback as the last argument](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis/blob/75b0bc97ea3c9b140866fb8fa9888c1aec471943/index.js#L751-L769).

So doing something like

```
client.publish('channel', 'message', function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
});
```

should work as expected.

Comment: Will check and report back. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Confirmed, it does.