# How to call a method in a catch clause on an object defined in a try clause?

Tags: scala

I am creating a redis pubsub client in a `try-catch` block. In the `try` block, the client is initialised with a callback to forward messages to a client. If there's a problem sending the message to the client, an exception will be thrown, in which case I need to stop the redis client. Here's the code:

```
try {
  val redisClient = RedisPubSub(
    channels = Seq(currentUserId.toString),
    patterns = Seq(),
    onMessage = (pubSubMessage: PubSubMessage) => {
      responseObserver.onValue(pubSubMessage.data)
    }
  )
}
catch {
  case e: RuntimeException =>
    // redisClient isn't defined here...
    redisClient.unsubscribe(currentUserId.toString)
    redisClient.stop()
    messageStreamResult.complete(Try(true))
    responseObserver.onCompleted()
}
```

The problem is that the redis client val isn't defined in the catch block because there may have been an exception creating it. I also can't move the `try-catch` block into the callback because there's no way (that I can find) of referring to the redisClient object from within the callback (`this` doesn't resolve).

To solve this I'm instantiating `redisClient` as a `var` outside the `try-catch` block. Then inside the `try` block I stop the client and assign a new `redisPubSub` (created as above) to the `redisClient` var. That's an ugly hack which is also error prone (e.g. if there genuinely *is* a problem creating the second client, the catch block will try to call methods on an erroneous object).

Is there a better way of writing this code so that I can correctly call `stop()` on the redisClient if an exception is raised when trying to send the message to the responseObserver?

**Update**

I've just solved this using promises. Is there a simpler way though?

Comment: Since your only expression in the try clause is your `RedisPubSub` instantiation, I don't see how you could call a method on `redisClient` if an exception occurs. If an exception is thrown, the `redisClient` variable is null.

Comment: @LomigMégard Well that's the whole point of my question isn't it. If I get a runtime exception because of errors receiving messages, I want to shut down the client, but I can't get a reference to the variable because an exception could also have been thrown initialising it.

Answer (score 0):

That exception handler is *not* going to be invoked if there is a problem sending the message.  It is for problems in setting up the client.  This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25995158/464309) talks about handling errors when sending messages.

As for the callback referring to the client, I think you want to register the callback *after* creating the client rather than trying to pass the callback in when you create it.  Here is some [sample code from Debashish Ghosh](http://debasishg.blogspot.com/2010/04/pubsub-with-redis-and-akka-actors.html) that does this.

Presumably that callback is going to run in another thread, so if it uses `redisClient` you'll have to be careful about concurrency.  Ideally the callback could get to the client object through some argument.  If not, then perhaps using `volatile` would be the easiest way to deal with that, although I suspect you'd eventually get into trouble if multiple callbacks can fail at once.  Perhaps use an actor to manage the client connection, as Debashish has done?

Comment: The code I've written works. I tried instantiating the client and then passing the callback, but the client is a case class and the callbacks are immutable. I don't think I need to use actors because I'm creating one redis client per client of my server, so everything is immutable. I'm not sharing the redis client between different threads. Also, the library I'm using (rediscala) uses actors behind the scenes. You're probably right about the exception handler not being invoked though, I'll dig deeper, thanks.